# TransientPropertyValueException in Mapstruct created entities

Tags: spring-data-jpa, mapstruct

Can anyone give a hint what can go wrong with saving two related entities to database.

The only problem is that these entities created out from data transfer objects with help of MapStruct.

- Testcase where I save fresh entities to db works fine.
- Testcase where I save entities created from Dtos to db fail.

Unit test create and save OrderHeader with 2  OrderLine to database - works with NO issues

```
public void testOrderHeaderRepository() {  
    OrderLine orderLine1 = OrderLine.builder().quantityOrdered(1).productId(1L).build();  
    OrderLine orderLine2 = OrderLine.builder().quantityOrdered(1).productId(2L).build();  
    OrderHeader orderHeader = OrderHeader.builder().name("test order").build();  
      
    orderHeader.setOrderLines(new HashSet<OrderLine>() {{  
    add(orderLine1);  
    add(orderLine2);  
    }});  
    orderLine1.setOrderHeader(orderHeader);  
    orderLine2.setOrderHeader(orderHeader);  
      
    OrderHeader orderHeaderSaved = orderHeaderRepository.save(orderHeader);
}
```

Unit test create OrderHeaderDto and 2  OrderLineDto, convert them to OrderHeader with 2  OrderLine and  save  to database - throws exception

```
public void testOrderHeaderRepositoryWithDto() {  
  
OrderLineDto orderLine1 = OrderLineDto.builder().quantityOrdered(1).productId(1L).build();  
OrderLineDto orderLine2 = OrderLineDto.builder().quantityOrdered(1).productId(2L).build();  
OrderHeaderDto orderHeaderDto = OrderHeaderDto.builder().name("test order").build();  

orderHeaderDto.setOrderLines(new HashSet<OrderLineDto>() {{  
    add(orderLine1);  
    add(orderLine2);  
}});  
orderLine1.setOrderHeader(orderHeaderDto);  
orderLine2.setOrderHeader(orderHeaderDto);  
  
OrderHeader orderHeader = orderHeaderMapper.dtoToEntity(orderHeaderDto, new CycleAvoidingMappingContext());  
  
OrderHeader orderHeaderSaved = orderHeaderRepository.save(orderHeader);
```

throws exception

```
org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing : com.springcloud.sbsuite.orders.domain.OrderLine.orderHeader -> com.springcloud.sbsuite.orders.domain.OrderHeader
```

Here are main classes involved
two entities classes OrderHeader and OrderLine

```
@Entity  
@Data  
@NoArgsConstructor  
@AllArgsConstructor  
@Builder
public class OrderHeader extends BaseEntity {  
  
private String name;  
  
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "orderHeader", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)  
@EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude // Exclude this field from hash code calculation  
private Set<OrderLine> orderLines = new HashSet<>();  
}


@Entity  
@Data  
@NoArgsConstructor  
@AllArgsConstructor  
@Builder  
public class OrderLine extends BaseEntity {  
  
private Integer quantityOrdered;  
  
@ToString.Exclude  
@ManyToOne  
@JoinColumn(name = "order_header_id") // Specifies the column name for the foreign key  
@EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude // Exclude this field from hash code calculation  
private OrderHeader orderHeader;  
  
private Long productId;  
  
}
```

With corresponding dto's

```
@Data  
@NoArgsConstructor  
@AllArgsConstructor  
@Builder  
public class OrderHeaderDto {  
  
// BaseEntity props omitted 

private String name;  
@EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude // Exclude this field from hash code calculation  
private Set<OrderLineDto> orderLines = new HashSet<>();  
}

@Data  
@NoArgsConstructor  
@AllArgsConstructor  
@Builder  
public class OrderLineDto {  
  
// BaseEntity props omitted 
  
@ToString.Exclude  
@EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude // Exclude this field from hash code calculation  
private OrderHeaderDto orderHeader;  

private Long productId;  
private Integer quantityOrdered;  
}
```

Both entity classes have their jpa repositories

```
public interface OrderHeaderRepository extends JpaRepository<OrderHeader, Long> {  
}
public interface OrderLineRepository extends JpaRepository<OrderLine, Long> {  
}
```

I use MapStruct to convert dto to entities

```
@Mapper(uses = {DateMapper.class, OrderLineMapper.class, AddressMapper.class})
public interface OrderHeaderMapper {
    @Mapping(target = "orderLines", source = "orderLines")
    OrderHeader dtoToEntity(OrderHeaderDto orderHeaderDto, @Context CycleAvoidingMappingContext cycleAvoidingMappingContext);
    @InheritInverseConfiguration
    OrderHeaderDto entityToDto(OrderHeader orderHeader, @Context CycleAvoidingMappingContext cycleAvoidingMappingContext);
}

@Mapper(uses = {DateMapper.class})
public interface OrderLineMapper {
    @Mapping(target = "orderHeader", source = "orderHeader")
    OrderLine dtoToEntity(OrderLineDto orderLineDto, @Context CycleAvoidingMappingContext cycleAvoidingMappingContext);
    OrderLineDto entityToDto(OrderLine orderLine, @Context CycleAvoidingMappingContext cycleAvoidingMappingContext);
}
```